# AWS Java Exception: Library source does not match the bytecode for class KmsMasterKeyProvider

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am working with this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-example-code.html

There is some strange error when I call code from the example:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> software/amazon/awssdk/core/interceptor/ExecutionInterceptor  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1087)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

...

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> software/amazon/awssdk/core/interceptor/ExecutionInterceptor  at
> com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.kmssdkv2.KmsMasterKeyProvider.builder(KmsMasterKeyProvider.java:243)

I have installed this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-encryption-sdk-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Version `2.4.0` is current version, I tried `2.3.3` but the problem is same.

And when I go into class `KmsMasterKeyProvider` (that causes the problem) IntelliJ IDEA show this error. I reinstalled all Maven dependencies but with no luck. What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the way IntelliJ is considering the dependency can you try downgrading the dependency `software.amazon.awssdk` core to **2.20.57** and same version of `kms` dependency to **2.20.57** in pom